# Exporting CPT from dev site and import into live site?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-cli, export

Trying to figure out the best way of doing this with the WP CLI.

Right now I'm running:

```
wp export --dir=./tmp_posts/ --post__in=2656 --with_attachments
```

This creates an export file, but some of the fields for images just contain nodes like:

```
<wp:postmeta>

<wp:meta_key>_acf_section_0_sc_bg_img</wp:meta_key>

<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[field_587e95cc672a0]]></wp:meta_value>

</wp:postmeta>
```

Is is possible that importing this to the live site will actually bring over the images?

If there a better way to do this with custom post types? I use Migrate DB Pro but it seems overkill sometimes and was hoping to have a more simplistic approach for individual posts.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to ask somewhere that has ACF expertise, this isn't a general WordPress question

Comment: @TomJNowell Do you know of a preferred way of doing this without a plugin?

Comment: In all honesty I'd just do it and see if it works, you can try it out on a local copy or a staging site. Otherwise you will need to ask in ACF support or ACF communities, this isn't an ACF site, I'm actually leaning towards this question being offtopic as it's an ACF export/import question